# SQL Server network specific error

Tags: sql-server-2008

Well I'm trying to connect to my server computer's SQL Server but I got a Network Related Error all the times..

Tried everything, like: turning firewall off, opening port 1433, turning off the antivirus, changing some security options in sql server, etc...

What else can I do?!

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: are you trying to connect thru web application or thru SQL server management studio?

Comment: thru SQL server management studio...

Comment: Is the SQL Browser service running on the server? I not, start that and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

1. Open Management studio
2. Click on Connect -> Database engine
3. Click on Server name dropdown, then click on
4. In local server tab expand DataBase Engine
5. Select the Server instance , click ok.
6. Use windows or sql authentication based on what you had set up while installation.

Comment: thnx....didn't work :(( well it founds the server name only (computer name) without SQL Server Instance name on server....:( Also tried the server name but didn't work :((

Comment: Check this video and see if your sql server service is running or not http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFJq7V8mrWA